# How to take controls off video in Cargo

Tags: html, css, video

This is an issue that I keep running to and have not yet found a fix. I am using Cargo to create my portfolio website, and when I add videos that loop I would like to take of the controls so that it is entirely a gif. The reason why I don't want to convert my videos into gifs is because the difference of quality in video is very extreme.

Right now the videos are autoplaying with loop but the controls still are visible when the mouse is hovered over it.

```
<video width="670" height="376" src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c1633764/lastkiko.mp4" type="null" playsinline="" muted="" autoplay="" loop="" controls=""></video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

[Refer To Here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)

It states that the values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Comment: What an easy fix, thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind, the code worked but now the videos are not looping. Should I add back the loop=""

Comment: loop="" worked sorry about that !!

Comment: @mel im glad you figured it out sorry for the late reply been a long day.